# How load json data on table using datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying load json data on table using [datatables](http://datatables.net/)

The return of json from php is like this:

```
data = {
  "CLIENTES": {
    "0": {
      "ID": "1",
      "NOME": 'GABRIEL'
    },
    "1": {
      "ID": "2",
      "NOME": 'RODRIGUES'
    }
  }
}
```

In the documentation [columns data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#string) they say that I need to follow this structure:

```
table.DataTable({
  "ajax": url,
  columns: [
    {"data": "CLIENTES.ID"},
    {"data": "CLIENTES.NOME"}
  ]
});
```

But dont work, and  we know that the right acess to de data index is this way:

```
{"data": "CLIENTES['0'].ID"},
{"data": "CLIENTES['1'].ID"},
```

But need's to be dynamically, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new data for datatable without `CLIENTES` .... map is an option.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    data = {
      "CLIENTES": {
        "0": {
           "ID": "1",
           "NOME": 'GABRIEL'
        },
       "1": {
           "ID": "2",
           "NOME": 'RODRIGUES'
         }
       }
     };


   var newData = $.map(data.CLIENTES, function(el) { return el });

   $('#example').DataTable({
       data: newData,
       columns: [
       {"data": "ID"},
       {"data": "NOME"}
       ]
    });

  });
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/5/

Comment: This is a good answer if you haven't got say over what data you receive, but if you do then sending through only the required data is a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the 'CLIENTES' outer array and only return an array of the results in your PHP, you will be able to refer to the values like this:

```
    table.DataTable({
        "ajax": url,
        columns: [
          {"data": "ID"},
          {"data": "NOME"}
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do things to an object dynamically by using [for var in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var myArray = [] //an  empty array

for(var i in data){
    myData.push({"data": "CLIENTES[i].ID"})
    myData.push({"data": "CLIENTES[i].NOME"})        
}
```

then later you can do this

```
table.DataTable({
    "ajax": url,
    columns: myArray
});
```

but I suspect the way you write `{"data": "CLIENTES[i].ID"}` is wrong, though i havent used `datatables` before.

maybe something like this is more correct? it's how you usually get to object properties

```
for(var i in data){
    myData.push({"data": data.CLIENTES[i].ID})
    myData.push({"data": data.CLIENTES[i].NOME})        
}
```